# Is it is possible to copy from SnowFlake Database into Azure SQLDB with Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

Can someone confirm it's not possible to copy from SnowFlake to Azure SQLDB. When I attempt to copy to Azure SQLDB it the following error:

[image]

Is there anyway to copy from SnowFlake to an Azure SQLDB?

Thanks

Comment: you need to `enable staging` with blob storage which has Authentication using SAS URL

Comment: Yes, It is possible to copy from Snowflake to SQLDB. In copy activity, you need to `enable staging`.  Create a linked service for blob storage in staging account linked service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically as per MSFT Docs :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-snowflake?tabs=data-factory#direct-copy-from-snowflake

If sink data store and format are natively supported by the Snowflake COPY command, you can use the Copy activity to directly copy from Snowflake to sink.

SInce Azure SQL DB is not supported, you would have to enable a staging layer of Azure blob storage as below flow:

Snowflake>> Azure blob Staging layer >> Azure SQL database

you need to enable a staging layer property in copy activity

Comment: I created a staging layer of Azure blob, as suggested and it worked fine. Thank yo

Comment: glad it helped out